# change fraction format without affecting the jquery calculation

Tags: jquery, html

I have displayed the fraction value in div class and also i have calculated that value using jquery

```
<div class="score_new score_left number" id="element2" onclick="javascript:removecls='';">6/3</div>
<div class="score_right" id="element4" onclick="javascript:removecls='';">5/3</div>
```

Here is the sample Jquery code

```
var dig_new = $('#element2').html()+', '+$('#element4').html();
```

Now I need to change the fraction value format as custom without affecting the jquery calculation

6
     -
     3

How is it possible? If any one knows tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sup` superscript and `sub` subscript tags with slash char in between:

```
<div><sup>1</sup> &#8260; <sub>100</sub></div>
```

Rendered as:
   <sup>1</sup> ⁄ <sub>100</sub>

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fkmzv1om/)**

Comment: I have used some calculation in the fraction value. If i used the "<sup>,<sub>" options to fraction display, how can i get the fraction value for calculation?

Comment: @NitheesBavesh: you can get the html, parseInt to int and then do the calculation. something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dwukr8v3/